# Getting a compile error : 0x2 trying to open file <vfdmsg>

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to build http://chitchat.at.infoseek.co.jp/vmware/vfd.html (VS 2008, Windows Server 2008 x64) however I'm getting the following error messages:

```
Error   1   error : 0x2 trying to open file <vfdmsg>.   mc  lib
Error   2   error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Compiling Message - L:\src\lib\vfdmsg.mc"    lib lib
Error   3   error : 0x2 trying to open file <vfdmsg>.   mc  cmd
Error   4   error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Compiling Message - L:\src\cmd\vfdmsg.mc"    cmd cmd
Error   5   error : 0x2 trying to open file <vfdmsg>.   mc  gui
Error   6   error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Compiling Message - L:\src\gui\vfdmsg.mc"    gui gui
```

I have the windows 2008 SDK installed and I've googled this for a while now but I cant for the life of me figure out what this error means. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed this by noticing that the build step for vfdmsg.mc was:

```
mc $(InputName)
```

Where $(InputName) resolved to vfdmsg, not vfdmsg.mc

Fixed by replacing this with the following build step:

```
mc $(InputFileName)
```